# python gnupg how to pgp encrypt a file without having to specify a homedir, or store key in the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnupg

I need to write an automation task to use python gnupg lib to pgp encrypt a file.

I will get the encryption key from secure cloud, and my preference is not to store the key in local disk for security reason.

I know you can specify a homedir and you can also import key, but I was wonder if it's possible to not specify a homedir, and also if we can get away from not saving the key into a file.

I am open to any python lib that can get this pgp encryption done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To encrypt the data you only need the public key, so there's no inherent security issues with storing that on the automated system.  Since you're not being too specific on what type of security issue is of concern, I'm going to have to assume that you mean you don't want to permanently store information that identifies the key or key owner to whom the data being encrypted actually is.

If you don't specify a homedir via any of the standard methods of whichever library is used then GPG will default to the homedir of the user invoking the script (by default this will be `$HOME/.gnupg`).  Futhermore to, to encrypt to a public key it must be available on disk at the time it is actually used.  You can get rid of it straight afterwards, though, if you want.

To create a temporary homedir to work with in the `/tmp` directory (not recommended, but can be useful on some systems like Tails Linux), do this:

```
import os
import os.path

newhome = "/tmp/.gnupg"

if os.path.exists(newhome) is True:
    print("The {0} directory already exists.".format(newhome))
else:
    print("Creating the {0} directory.".format(newhome))
    os.mkdir(newhome)
    os.chmod(newhome, 0o700)
```

The rest of this example uses the GPGME Python bindings.

Assuming you've downloaded the public key as a local ASCII armoured file then this will import it to the new temporary homedir:

```
import gpg

keyfile = "/tmp/key.asc"
c = gpg.Context(armor=True, home_dir=newhome)
with open(keyfile, "rb") as f:
    keydata = f.read()

c.op_import(keydata)
result = c.op_import_result()
```

Since you know which key you're getting I'll assume you also already know it's key ID or fingerprint, so we follow straight on with this:

```
key_id = "0x12345678DEADBEEF"
filename = "/path/to/secret_plans.txt"

rkey = list(gpg.Context().keylist(pattern=key_id, secret=False))
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    text = f.read()

ciphertext, result, sign_result = c.encrypt(text, recipients=rkey, sign=False,
                                            always_trust=True)
with open("{0}.asc".format(filename), "wb") as fa:
    fa.write(ciphertext)
```

Then once it's done you can delete `newhome` any way you like.

Greater details of how (and why) this module does what it does are available in the [GPGME Python bindings HOWTO](https://dev.gnupg.org/source/gpgme/browse/master/lang/python/docs/src/gpgme-python-howto) (Org Mode source file) and a [HTML version is here](http://files.au.adversary.org/crypto/gpgme-python-howto.html).